# Idiom or phrase to describe no choice

Tags: phrase-request, idiom-request

Is there any phrase or idiom to describe a situation where someone has no any other choices but only one final choice . The context of the sentence:

> There is no evidence to associate the accused to the crime, **leaving the judge with no choice** but to acquit him from the offence

Comment: "leave X no choice but to" **is** an idiom, and it works perfectly here.

Comment: Related but not quite the same is Hobson's choice https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobson%27s_choice

Comment: Why don’t you want to use your current wording?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We sometimes say someone's **hand is forced** or that something **forces someone's hand** to mean that they are compelled to do something they didn't want to do, or didn't want to do yet.  For example,

> [I tried to get you to see reason but you forced my hand.](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Desolation/jGAKBgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22forced%20my%20hand%22&pg=PA249&printsec=frontcover&bsq=%22forced%20my%20hand%22)

> [By not cooperating you've forced my hand, before we've even started.](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Tunnel_Vision/ZHEOBAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22forced%20my%20hand%22&pg=PA34&printsec=frontcover&bsq=%22forced%20my%20hand%22)

> [The president, with his jurisdiction over military power, temporarily had the upper hand.  Congress, however, could soon force his hand.](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_South_Vs_The_South/RAOUzFEmleUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22force%20his%20hand%22&pg=PA108&printsec=frontcover&bsq=%22force%20his%20hand%22)

References:
https://www.dictionary.com/browse/force-someone-s-hand
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/force%20someone%27s%20hand
https://www.oysterenglish.com/idiom-force-someones-hand.html